# Sort , Unique not working Powershell for this string

Tags: powershell, sorting, unique

Be advised this formatted incorrectly in here.
This below is 3 lines per vm.

1. Column Name [6]
2. dashes [pseudo underline for column name]
3. vm info

This info is a Variable type is string.

I am trying to sort unique the header and dashes to one line. and to remove the blank lines....  Nothing works.. tried Get-Unique, Sort -Unique, etc

```
    Cluster             Name            Guest VMHost                       Vcenter                       PowerState
    -------             ----            ----- ------                       -------                       ----------
    testesxlabcluster01 testvm5v       testesxhlab01.lab.vm.com testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com PoweredOff



    Cluster             Name            Guest VMHost                       Vcenter                       PowerState
    -------             ----            ----- ------                       -------                       ----------
    testesxlabcluster01 testvm4v       testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com PoweredOff



    Cluster             Name            Guest VMHost                       Vcenter                       PowerState
    -------             ----            ----- ------                       -------                       ----------
    testesxlabcluster01 testvm3v       testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com PoweredOff



    Cluster             Name            Guest                               VMHost                       Vcenter                       PowerState
    -------             ----            -----                               ------                       -------                       ----------
    testesxlabcluster01 testvm2v Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit) testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com PoweredOn



    Cluster             Name            Guest                               VMHost                       Vcenter                       PowerState
    -------             ----            -----                               ------                       -------                       ----------
    testesxlabcluster01 testvm1v Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit) testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com PoweredOn
```

To Look like this...

```
Cluster             Name            Guest                   VMHost                       Vcenter                       PowerState
-------             ----            -----                   ------                       -------                       ----------
testesxlabcluster01 testtestvm5v                        testesxhlab01.lab.vm.com    testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com       PoweredOff
testesxlabcluster01 testtestvm4v                        testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com    testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com      PoweredOff
testesxlabcluster01 testtestvm3v                        testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com    testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com      PoweredOff
testesxlabcluster01 testtestvm2v Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit) testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com   testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com      PoweredOn
testesxlabcluster01 testtestvm1v Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit) testesxhlab02.lab.vm.com   testvcntrlab01.lab.vm.com      PoweredOn
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use string operators? Any C# functions are callable from powershell

Comment: Please explain or show an example.

Comment: could you format your question, use the code tag for the bottom half. I'm not fully understanding what you're asking here

Comment: I do not know C#

Comment: I can provide some C#... first I need to know, is this stored in a variable? where is this output coming from? a lot of time you can do this with a `| select`

Comment: Hmm I do not see a way to edit my post to format it.

Comment: click the edit button?

Comment: Yes this info is in a Variable. That I got from a ps script i wrote to list this info 
for a vm...  a findvm stript.. I then added the output to a Variable via Out-string.  this is a list of 5 VMs each with the same header info... when $vminfo to display the output.  I see header, dashes and vminfo for each line.  I only want the header {column names} ONCE and no blank lines

Comment: I can only edit my comments not the post do not see an edit for post

Comment: Where is this output coming from? If from PowerShell, do _not_ use `Format-Table` to write output. That creates string output. If you want access to the properties, do not use `Format-Table`.

Comment: @nixgeek you're going to have to post the script. This isn't enough information to construct an answer

Comment: Found the 'EDIT' button.. it is now formatted.

Comment: Where is the output coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You said it is stored in a variable, so we'll call that `$var`

You need to show me the call that generates the data that is stored in `$var`...

First, you'd run the command that gets the data

`$var = Command arg1 arg2`

Do not store any `Out-String` or `Format-Table` output into the `$var` so that it is a PSobject and not a string.

Then you should be able to do a "select as" (is what I like to call it):

```
$var = $var | select @{l='original_header1';e='new_header1'},@{l='original_header2';e='new_header2'}
```

If you want to output what's in the variable

`C:>$var`

I highly suggest testing this at the command line before scripting it.

Comment: Hmm I am able to do a findstr and that works... when Get.type() 

True     True     String[]                                 System.Array